# Java code to import MySql data into hive through sqoop: ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool - Hive exited with status 44

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have written following Java code to import MySql data into hive through Sqoop.

```
import com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions.IncrementalMode;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;
public class Test_sqlTohdfs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();      
            options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.150:3306/college_mysql");  
            options.setUsername("root");
            options.setPassword("root");            
            options.setTableName("student");
            options.setSplitByCol("rollNo");            
            options.setHiveDatabaseName("College_hive");
            options.setOverwriteHiveTable(true);
            options.setHiveTableName("stud_02");
            options.setHiveImport(true);            
            int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);    

        }
}
```

I have successfully imported MySql data into Hdfs file but when I am trying to import MySql data into hive with above code it gives following error, I tried a lot but didn't get anything to solve it. Please help me to resolve it, thanks in advance.

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 44
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:385)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:335)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:239)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at com.test.Test_sqlTohdfs.main(Test_sqlTohdfs.java:25)
```

Comment: This is probably a permissions issue of some kind. I highly recommend asking this on dev@sqoop.apache.org.

Comment: did you get any answer? Any progress on the issue?